# Algebraic multiplicity of a zero eigenvalue, in a generalized eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Consider the generalized eigenvalue problem (GEVP)

$\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{v} = \lambda \boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{v}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
$

where $\boldsymbol{A}, \boldsymbol{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are both singular.

(1) Is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ for the GEVP always the same as the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ for $\boldsymbol{A}$? And is the proof as simple as noting that for $\lambda = 0$ $\eqref{1}$ is

$\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{v} = 0.
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}
$

(2) Consider that the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ are known. I understand the count of positive, negative and null eigenvalues of the GEVP can be known, in the case where $\boldsymbol{B}$ is positive definitive [[1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0602386.pdf)], but can some insight be gained in this case where both $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ are singular?

Thank you!